# C2DM - TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm, user-accounts

I know that one user account registered to C2DM can handle up to 100 apps with C2DM.

My question is this:
Can the registered user handle more than 100apps spread on different devices?
I want to have a big group of people that share one single Google
account.

Is it possible?
Is the TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS referred just to the apps on a single
devices, or is it referred to the apps that one single Google account (registered user)
can handle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the Android C2DM [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#arch) (emphasis mine):

> Registration ID
>
> An ID issued by the C2DM servers to the Android application that
>   allows it to receive messages. Once the application has the
>   registration ID, it sends it to the third-party application server,
>   which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive
>   messages for a given application. In other words, **a registration ID
>   is tied to a particular application running on a particular device**.

From this little snippet, it's fair to *assume* that the 100 registration limit is **per account per device**. So for example, if account `bob@gmail.com` has 100 (C2DM enabled) apps on device `A`, and wishes to add a *new* (C2DM enabled) app on device `B`, then it should be fine. This of course assumes that the number of (C2DM enabled) apps on device `B` is `< 100` at that point.